# Relative difference between joint probability and product of marginals.

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

Let $\{p_{i,j};i\geq 1, j\geq 1\}$ be a joint probability distribution, and $\{p_{i,\cdot};i\geq 1\}$ and $\{p_{\cdot,j};j\geq 1\}$ be two corresponding marginal distributions. Does the following inequality always hold?
$$  \left(\sum_{i,j}p_{i,j}^2-\sum_{i}p_{i,\cdot}^2 \times \sum_{j}p_{\cdot,j}^2\right)^2\leq 
\left(\sum_{i,j}p_{i,j}^2-\sum_{i,j}p_{i,j}^2 \times \sum_{i,j}p_{i,j}^2\right)^2$$

Note that the troublesome issue in proving this inequality (if it is true) is that the expression within the parenthesis on the left, $\sum_{i,j}p_{i,j}^2-\sum_{i}p_{i,\cdot}^2 \times \sum_{j}p_{\cdot,j}^2$, could be positive (in which case the proof is easy) or negative (in which case I don't see a proof).